# Is it possible to remove dead code using CppCheck?

Tags: c++, cppcheck, dead-code

Is it possible to remove C++ dead code using CppCheck?

If so, how?

Comment: Cppcheck does not edit source code, it can only help to find issues in it. You can decide to remove dead code based on some warning or error from Cppcheck.

Comment: @ks1322, I am using stand alone CppCheck GUI and I saw no such warning or error.

Comment: Do not close this question. It is not asking for a recommendation on software to use. It is asking about a binary yes/no feature of existing software. This question is answerable, and I think a very good use of the site.

Comment: `clang-tidy` can do that task locally: it reports about unused functions in a source file if they are not declared in a .h file.

Answer (score 1):

Like other code analyzers, Cppcheck helps you find dead code, but it cannot fix the code automatically. You should examine the code yourself and decide whether and how to fix it.

Analyzers do not fix code automatically for two reasons:

1. It may not be an error. First, static analyzers may issue [false positive warning](https://pvs-studio.com/en/blog/terms/6461/).  Second, dead code doesn't mean it's not needed. Perhaps the code is executed in other compilation modes.
2. Even if the analyzer has detected a real error, it is not always obvious how to fix it. Even a human can make a mistake and fix the code incorrectly, so it is definitely not a good idea to entrust it to a machine. Here is a good [example](https://pvs-studio.com/en/blog/posts/cpp/0776/) on this topic.